# Find && Delete Duplicate vector elements in a for loop

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates

I have these files in a `vector`

```
vector<string> myFileNames ={"TestFile1","TestFile2","copiedFile1","copiedFile2","copiedFile3"};
```

Should only have unique file left in list i.e. `test file 1&2`

```
vector<string> duplicateFilesFound;
```

To be filled with files that duplicates i.e. `copiedFile 1, 2 && 3` are duplicates

```
vector<string> myMd5Strings;
```

Filled with `md5` hash values

```
string target = " ";  
    int count = 0;  
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myFileNames.size(); ++i)  
    {  
        target = myMd5Strings[i];  
        for (unsigned int k = 1; k < myFileNames.size(); ++k)   
        {  
            if (target == myMd5Strings[k])  
            {  
                myFileNames.erase(myFileNames.begin() + k);  
                duplicateFilesFound.push_back(myFileNames[k]);  
            }  
        }  
        cout << "Duplicate Count is : " << duplicateFilesFound.size() << endl;  
    }
```

Comment: Your original vector does not contain duplicate names.  Secondly, removing duplicates from a vector can be done in two function calls, `std::sort` and then `std::unique` with an `erase`.  Also, what is your question?

Comment: @C.Fitz This would be a whole lot easier if you had a struct that has the filename and its MD5 value, and have a container of this struct.  Having two separate vectors complicates the issue.  But I still don't see a question from you.

Comment: @CFitz  What if there were 100 filenames? Your loops would, at worst case, do 10,000 iterations to erase duplicates.  Increase that to 1,000 names to search.  That is 1,000,000 iterations.  See where this is going?  Your loops would "work", but at the cost of taking an inordinate amount of time to complete  if the file list is large.

Comment: @C.Fitz I also don't understand your usage of the md5 vector.  First you do this: `target = myMd5Strings[i];` then you do this: `if (target == myMd5Strings[k])` Why not just remove file `i` directly?  What is the `k` loop supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @C.Fitz I posted an answer that shows usage of the struct, and also point out at least two flaws with your attempted set of loops.

Comment: @PaulMcKensie Is their a way of passing my two vectors into the struct you have shown, they have been filled with fileNames && corresponding md5 hash values already in my program, i just need to remove all files(including the original) with matching md5 hash values from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One mistake (maybe there are others) is that you are first getting the MD5 to test, but then your inner `k` loop will erroneously erase the first item matching the hash.  For example, if your target (the `i` value) is at element 2, your loop doesn't check if `k == 2` so as to skip over this first occurrence.

The test should be:

```
 if ( i != k && target == myMd5Strings[k])
```

The second issue is that if you erase an item, you need to keep the `k` value where it is and not increment.  Otherwise you will skip over the next item to check and miss this item if it matches the hash.

But even with pointing these gotchas out, your attempt is an order of `n^2` -- you have 100 names, that is 10,000 iterations, 1,000 names, 1,000,000 iterations, etc.  At the end of the day, this will perform poorly on large lists.

---

The approach mentioned below is logarithmic (due to the sort) in time, not quadratic, thus executing much faster for large list sizes.

But a few structural changes could be done.  A better approach would be to store the file name, along with MD5 hash in a single struct.  Then declare a container of this struct.

```
struct file_info
{
   std::string filename;
   std::string md5hash;
};
//...
std::vector<file_info> fInfoV;
```

Once you have this, then everything becomes very simple using some basic algorithm functions.

To remove duplicates with a certain md5 hash can be done by first sorting the list using the hash value as the sort criteria, and then removing the duplicates using `std::unique` and then `erase`.

```
   #include <algorithm>
   //...
   std::sort(fInfoV.begin(), fInfoV.end(), 
             [](const file_info&f1, const file_info& f2) 
             { f1.md5hash < f2.md5hash; });

   // uniqueify the vector
   auto iter = std::unique(fInfoV.begin(), fInfoV.end(), 
                           [](const file_info& f1, const file_info& f2) 
                           { f1.md5hash == f2.md5hash; });

   // for kicks, get the number of duplicates found
   auto duplicateCount = std::distance(iter, fInfoV.end());     
   cout << "There are " << duplicateCount << " duplicates found";

   // erase these duplicates
   fInfoV.erase(iter, fInfoV.end());
```

The code above, sorts, uniquifies, and erases the duplicates.  I threw in [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to show you that you can get the number of duplicates without having to create another vector.  The code above also overcomes the need to write loops checking for equivalent loop indices, making sure you reseat the inner index, checking for bounds, etc.

As to time complexity:

The [std::sort function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is guaranteed to have logarithmic complexity.
The [std::unique function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) has linear complexity:

So this will perform much better for large lists.

Comment: To remove duplicate files its not enough to check that the MD5 is the same, as it can only tell you that if its different its not the same file. You would also have to compare the files that has the same MD5 to be sure they are actual copies. So different MD5, they are not the same, same MD5 they might be the same.